# fadeIn and fadeOut - cannot ready property undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main nav bar which I am turning into a full width sticky on scroll. Now I am trying to incorporate a fade in/out for the full width white banner which appears on scroll (behind the nav).

Getting an undefined error when scrolling, and the fadeIn/Out is not working.

Here is my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- STICKY HEADER -->
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {fadeFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("head");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function fadeFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky").fadeIn();
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky").fadeOut();
  }
}
</script>



<style>

#head {
    z-index: 10;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
    
  .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
</style>
```

Console error:

> Cannot read property 'fadeIn' of undefined.

I suspect my jQuery is probably not correct?

UPDATED CODE - Except that it only runs after page load, but not every time page is scrolled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var header = document.getElementById("head");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function addSticky() {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    $('.sticky').addClass('fadeInDown');
    $('.sticky').removeClass('fadeInUp');
    $('.sticky').addClass('animated');
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('fadeInDown');
    $('.subnav-sticky').removeClass('fadeOutUp');
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('animated');

}
function removeSticky() {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('fadeOutUp');
    $('.subnav-sticky').removeClass('fadeInUp');
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > sticky) {
        addSticky();
    } 
    else {
        removeSticky();             
    } 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing javascript methods with jQuery ones, `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` are jQuery functions but you're not triggering those methods on a jQuery object.

In your case `header` should be wrapped with the dollar function:

```
var $header = $('#head')
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$header.addClass('sticky').fadeIn()
```

I'll say that you may not even need jQuery and you could do these animations using the same `sticky` class.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my code (see above), except that it only works after initial page load, but not every time you scroll the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who helped. I updated my script and created a new css class. Thew new css class is to handle the transition for the sticky nav.

Here is my solution.

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var header = document.getElementById("head");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 0) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    header.classList.add("transitions");
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('fadeInDown');
    $('.subnav-sticky').removeClass('fadeOutUp');
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('animated');   
    } 
    
    else {
    header.classList.add("transitions");
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('fadeOutUp');
    $('.subnav-sticky').removeClass('fadeInUp');
    $('.subnav-sticky').addClass('animated');   
    }
  });
```

And the new css class

```
.transitions {
    transition: all 0.9s   
}
```